# Roman Numeral C++ Programming Conversion Issue

Tags: c++

I am currently developing some code that is used to convert an inputted integer to  ROMAN numerals. It is working how it should be except for the cases where I am using the character I, it isn't adding them up correctly. I have done the same syntax as the other characters which work so I am baffled as to why it doesn't work for the "I" character. Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
else if(roman_Numeral == 'V')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral, 2) != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral - 5;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral + 5;
            continue;
        }
    }

    else if(roman_Numeral == 'I')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral), 2 != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral -1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral += 1 ;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
        break;
}
cout << arabic_Numeral << endl;
return 0;
```

The other characters, such as M, C, D etc are similar in layout, however with I obviously the desired output for something such as VI is 6 and it outputs 4. Any help would be appreciated.

The complete code is:

```
    #include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::string numerals = "IVXLCDM";

int main()
{
char roman_Numeral;
int arabic_Numeral = 0;

cout << "Enter the Roman Numeral in Capital letters (e.g. CCXIX) : ";
while(cin.get(roman_Numeral))
{
    if(roman_Numeral == 'M')
        arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral + 1000;

    else if(roman_Numeral == 'D')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral, 5) != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral - 500;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral + 500;
            continue;
        }
    }

    else if(roman_Numeral == 'C')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral, 4) != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral - 100;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral + 100;
            continue;
        }
    }

    else if(roman_Numeral == 'L')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral, 3) != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral - 50;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral + 50;
            continue;
        }
    }

    else if(roman_Numeral == 'X')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral, 2) != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral - 10;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral + 10;
            continue;
        }
    }

    else if(roman_Numeral == 'V')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral, 2) != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral - 5;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral + 5;
            continue;
        }
    }




    else if(roman_Numeral == 'I')
    {
        roman_Numeral = cin.peek();
        if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral), 2 != std::string::npos)
        {
            arabic_Numeral = arabic_Numeral -1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            arabic_Numeral += 1 ;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
        break;
}
cout << arabic_Numeral << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I initially found the code online and will be making additional changes later on. Currently the most of the test combinations of my code works. It's just implementing the I's so I can get test for singular cases of I such as `III = 3,` etc. III currently outputs -1 which is obviosuly not correct. I believe the issue is soemthing to do with the way it adds them together but not entirely sure. I am fairly new to coding after all.

Kind regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @cuzzy01 Can you please add complete code?

Comment: Read `if(numerals.find(roman_Numeral), 2 != std::string::npos)` carefully.

Comment: I have seen it on LeetCode, maybe [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/#/solutions)will help you.

Comment: And `V` doesn't follow the "subtraction rule"; you can't write 45 as VL.

Comment: @molbdnilo hi mate, I'm not quite sure what you are getting at. I feel as if there is an issue with the 2 but not entirely sure.

Comment: @alDiablo Added the full code mate.

Comment: @cuzzy01 Compare it to the other, similar, line. (They're not identical.)

Comment: [this](https://pastebin.com/hePr6F9E) is a roman numeral converter I wrote out of boredom, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. The code indeed has a bug for the 'I' section. Just read the code carefully and try to compare it with other working sections. **Hint**: missing parenthesis ;)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.